# Upload multiple JSON files but not all at once on IPFS using moralis

Tags: ipfs, moralis

I want to create NFT’s . So i want all json files in directory (/ipfs/CID/1.json,2.json,3.json) but i dont want want to reveal them instantly thats why I will upload only that json files that i want to reveal instantly and then add json files in ipfs to reveal NFTs later.
I want to upload multiple json files on IPFS but not all at once . Moralis uploadFolder working fine but when it try to upload another .json file its parent hash is different.

Example :-

I upload 2 json file in /json folder then moralis upload folder returns me with

/ipfs/CID/1.json
/ipfs/CID/2.json

in this case CID is same and that what i want but when i upload another 3.json file it returns me with another CID

/ipfs/NEW CID/3.json

Answer (score 0):

We can’t use decentralized storage like IPFS, because the URIs in IPFS are hashes of unique pieces of content and we can’t have completely unique URIs for every token in ERC1155.

Refer:- https://rameerez.com/problems-and-technical-nuances-of-nft-immutability-and-ipfs/

Answer (score 0):

you will have to send different requests
If you send it on request moralis will return same base url
I faced the same issue, I came up with a solution, I wrote a script which read images and json from a file structure and upload images to ipfs
you can see my code
https://github.com/RajaFaizanNazir/bulk_IPFS_pin_differentCID
if you face any issue or confusing, feel free to ask me